# Can't understand Perl regex replace behavour

Tags: regex, perl

I have some text that's piped from another command that looks like so:

```
source:project_dbt.common.business_days
source:project_dbt.common.cms_compare
source:project_dbt.common.cms_provider_national
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Claims_Reassignment-Sub-File_rta9-bts3
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Address-Sub-File_je57-c47h
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Base-Provider-Enrollment-File_ykfi-ffzq
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Secondary-Specialty_n48j-8qtj
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Part-D_Medicare-Provider-Utilization-and-Payment-Data-Par_icvy-hptt
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Physician-Supplier_Medicare-Physician-and-Other-Supplier-National-Pro_5fr6-cch3
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_data_provider-data_dataset_mj5m-pzi6_National_Downloadable_File
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_download_nppes_NPPES_Data_Dissemination
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-Dataset-2019-Reporti_qsys-b88w
source:project_dbt.common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-Dataset-2020-Reporti_txng-a8vj
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_b
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_d
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_snf_claims_quality_measures
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_snf_health_deficiencies
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_snf_mds_quality_measures
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_snf_provider_information
source:project_dbt.common.medicare_snf_quality_reporting_program_provider_data
source:project_dbt.common.offices_v3
source:project_dbt.common.open_payments_providers_supplementary
source:project_dbt.common.provider_per_zip_v6
source:project_dbt.common.providers_per_team_v1
source:project_dbt.common.tam_predictors_v1
source:project_dbt.common.tam_results_per_provider_all_v2
source:project_dbt.common.tam_results_per_provider_latest
source:project_dbt.common.tam_territory_components_v1
source:project_dbt.common.territories_per_zip_v2
source:project_dbt.common.territories_v2
source:project_dbt.common.usa_census_data_20201022
source:project_dbt.geo.simplemaps_uszips
source:project_dbt.geo.zip
```

And I want to modify it for input to a another command to run with `xargs`.

I tried to implement this with `perl` like so:

```sh
cat /tmp/myfile.txt \
  | perl -pe 's{^(source:project_dbt\.)(.+)$}{mycompany_$2 sav_$2}m'
```

so that I can get the desired output (i.e. I just want to repeat the second capture group with 2 different prefixes):

```
mycompany_common.business_days sav_common.business_days
mycompany_common.cms_compare sav_common.cms_compare
mycompany_common.cms_provider_national sav_common.cms_provider_national
mycompany_common.sav_-File_rta9-bts3 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-sav_Claims_Reassignment-Sub-File_rta9-bts3
mycompany_common.sav_-File_je57-c47h sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-sav_Enrollment_Address-Sub-File_je57-c47h
mycompany_common.sav_-Enrollment-File_ykfi-ffzq sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Base-sav_Provider-Enrollment-File_ykfi-ffzq
mycompany_common.sav_-8qtj sav_common.sav_gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Secondary-Specialty_n48j-8qtj
mycompany_common.sav_-Provider-Utilization-and-Payment-Data-Par_icvy-hptt sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Part-D_Medicare-Provider-Utilization-and-sav_Payment-Data-Par_icvy-hptt
mycompany_common.sav_-Physician-and-Other-Supplier-National-Pro_5fr6-cch3 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Physician-Supplier_Medicare-Physician-and-Other-sav_Supplier-National-Pro_5fr6-cch3
mycompany_common.sav_sav_common.gov_cms_data_provider-data_dataset_mj5m-pzi6_National_Downloadable_File
mycompany_common.gov_cms_download_nppes_NPPES_Data_Dissemination sav_common.gov_cms_download_nppes_NPPES_Data_Dissemination
mycompany_common.sav_-Detailed-Dataset-2019-Reporti_qsys-b88w sav_common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-sav_Dataset-2019-Reporti_qsys-b88w
mycompany_common.sav_-Detailed-Dataset-2020-Reporti_txng-a8vj sav_common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-sav_Dataset-2020-Reporti_txng-a8vj
mycompany_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_b sav_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_b
mycompany_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_d sav_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_d
mycompany_common.medicare_snf_claims_quality_measures sav_common.medicare_snf_claims_quality_measures
mycompany_common.medicare_snf_health_deficiencies sav_common.medicare_snf_health_deficiencies
mycompany_common.medicare_snf_mds_quality_measures sav_common.medicare_snf_mds_quality_measures
mycompany_common.medicare_snf_provider_information sav_common.medicare_snf_provider_information
mycompany_common.medicare_snf_quality_reporting_program_provider_data sav_common.medicare_snf_quality_reporting_program_provider_data
mycompany_common.offices_v3 sav_common.offices_v3
mycompany_common.open_payments_providers_supplementary sav_common.open_payments_providers_supplementary
mycompany_common.provider_per_zip_v6 sav_common.provider_per_zip_v6
mycompany_common.providers_per_team_v1 sav_common.providers_per_team_v1
mycompany_common.tam_predictors_v1 sav_common.tam_predictors_v1
mycompany_common.tam_results_per_provider_all_v2 sav_common.tam_results_per_provider_all_v2
mycompany_common.tam_results_per_provider_latest sav_common.tam_results_per_provider_latest
mycompany_common.tam_territory_components_v1 sav_common.tam_territory_components_v1
mycompany_common.territories_per_zip_v2 sav_common.territories_per_zip_v2
mycompany_common.territories_v2 sav_common.territories_v2
mycompany_common.usa_census_data_20201022 sav_common.usa_census_data_20201022
mycompany_geo.simplemaps_uszips sav_geo.simplemaps_uszips
mycompany_geo.zip sav_geo.zip
```

But when running this, the results are:

```
 sav_common.business_daysays
 sav_common.cms_compareare
 sav_common.cms_provider_nationalnal
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Claims_Reassignment-Sub-File_rta9-bts3ts3
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Address-Sub-File_je57-c47h47h
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Base-Provider-Enrollment-File_ykfi-ffzqfzq
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Enrollment_Secondary-Specialty_n48j-8qtjqtj
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Part-D_Medicare-Provider-Utilization-and-Payment-Data-Par_icvy-hpttptt
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_Medicare-Physician-Supplier_Medicare-Physician-and-Other-Supplier-National-Pro_5fr6-cch3ch3
 sav_common.gov_cms_data_provider-data_dataset_mj5m-pzi6_National_Downloadable_Fileile
 sav_common.gov_cms_download_nppes_NPPES_Data_Disseminationion
 sav_common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-Dataset-2019-Reporti_qsys-b88w88w
 sav_common.gov_cms_openpaymentsdata_dataset_General-Payment-Data-Detailed-Dataset-2020-Reporti_txng-a8vj8vj
 sav_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_bt_b
 sav_common.medicare_provider_utilization_and_payment_part_dt_d
 sav_common.medicare_snf_claims_quality_measuresres
 sav_common.medicare_snf_health_deficienciesies
 sav_common.medicare_snf_mds_quality_measuresres
 sav_common.medicare_snf_provider_informationion
 sav_common.medicare_snf_quality_reporting_program_provider_dataata
 sav_common.offices_v3_v3
 sav_common.open_payments_providers_supplementaryary
 sav_common.provider_per_zip_v6_v6
 sav_common.providers_per_team_v1_v1
 sav_common.tam_predictors_v1_v1
 sav_common.tam_results_per_provider_all_v2_v2
 sav_common.tam_results_per_provider_latestest
 sav_common.tam_territory_components_v1_v1
 sav_common.territories_per_zip_v2_v2
 sav_common.territories_v2_v2
 sav_common.usa_census_data_20201022022
 sav_geo.simplemaps_uszipsips
 sav_geo.zipzip
```

I.e. the second capture group is not repeating, but instead the last 3 chars of each line are appended to each line...

I have tried a bunch of variations, I can't work out exactly what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I tried this, and worked just fine for me, using Perl v5.30.2 on macOS. Could it be some sort of inconsistent line ending issue (lf vs. crlf) causing the ^ and $ markers of the regex to match the lines of the input file strangely for you?

Comment: Same, got a correct (desired) with perl 5.26.1 on Linux. What version of Perl are you running, OP?And like kshetline mentioned, what EOL do you have with your file?

Comment: The problem is that your lines have a carriage return at the end and perl is expecting a unix/linix file with only a newline.  So the replacement includes the carriage return and then when you print the result the second half overwrites the first.  The data is actually right - but you can't see it properly.  You need to remove the carriage returns from the file.  So, how you fix it depends on whether the file is going back to a windows box afterwards or not.  If not you could just put a `\r` before the `$` in the search part of the regex and that way it won't be included in the capture group.

Comment: yes! piping through `tr -d '\r'` did the trick! Thank you! Not sure how I ended up there since I am on OSX...?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passing a file with Windows line endings (CRLF) to a build of Perl expecting unix line endings (LF).

Given the input

```
source:project_dbt.common.business_days␍␊
                   \___________________/|
                            $2          Removed by -l
```

the program emits

```
mycompany_common.business_days␍ sav_common.business_days␍␊
          \___________________/     \___________________/|
                   $2                        $2          Added by -l
```

which your terminal displays as

```
 sav_common.business_days_days
\_______________________/\___/
       Overwritten        From original
```

Convert the file to a unix file (e.g. using `dos2unix`) or strip out trailing CR (`s/\s+\z//;`).